# Can I pass dynamic props to components by state in v3?

Tags: javascript, react-router

I want to pass dynamic props to components by state in v3. But it didn't work.

It's show a warning "[react-router] You cannot change ; it will be ignored" when I use code below. Then in  component, it always shows this.props.userId is null.

```
class Root extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            userId: null,
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
            userId: "123",
        })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Router history={browserHistory}>
                <Route path="/TeachingResourceManagement">
                    <IndexRoute component={(props) => (<Login {...props} onChange={this.handleUserIdChange.bind(this)} userId={this.state.userId} />)}/>   
                </Route>
            </Router>
    )}
}
render(<Root />, document.getElementById("container"))
```

P.S. 
I had tried to use code below (use render to pass props) but it also didn't work and even couldn't render a scene normally.

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/TeachingResourceManagement">
        <IndexRoute render={(props) => (<Login {...props} onChange={this.handleUserIdChange.bind(this)} userId={this.state.userId} />)}/>   
    </Route>
</Router>
```